# How can I access multiple parameters that have been passed to a function?

Tags: angularjs

I have something like the following that allows me to successfully access a functions parameter:

HTML:

Angular:

```
$scope.showContent = function(attrs){
    $http({
        url: attrs,
        method: "POST"
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
        $scope.my_content = data; 
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.status = status; });
};
```

But what if I have more than one parameter? For example:

```
<div ng-click="showContent('parameter1', 'parameter2')">
```

I thought I could do something like `$scope.param1 = attrs[0]`, etc. but that didn't work. How can I access both parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the function like `$scope.showContent = function(p1, p2){` and use them like `$scope.param1 = p1`

Or use [the `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) inside your function like `$scope.param1 = arguments[0]`

The documentation for the `arguments` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: I realize now that this was a dumb question, but thanks for the answer! I'm still a newb.